# How can I use sub-functions for filtering?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have a rather complex condition for my `WHERE` query in the database. If I were to use straight `SQL` I probably would put that part of the SQL query into a named variable to signify its semantic purpose.

If I were to use straight `Linq` I would use a function-call that matches the `Where()` predicate where the function name would tell me the purpose of the filter.

Unfortunately one can't seem to use sub-functions in Linq to SQL because then the query cannot be resolvd to SQL.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Here is the original `Linq-to-SQL` query:

```
query = query.Where(
    f => f.Table1.Any(
        t1 =>
            (t1.Table2.Any(t2 => t2.Header == Decoder.Identifier
                && DbFunctions.Like(t2.Content, pattern)))
            ||
            (!t1.Table2.Any(t2 => t2.Header == Decoder.Identifier)
                && DbFunctions.Like(t1.Text, pattern))
        ));
```

What I would like is something like this:

```
query = query.Where(
    f => f.Table1.Any(
        t1 =>
            HasCondition1(t1, pattern)
            ||
            HasCondition2(t1, pattern)
        ));
```

Comment: What is the SQL query you are trying to recreate?

Comment: @klekmek edited question to incluse sample

Comment: LINQ isn't SQL. ORMs like EF Core deal with entities, not tables. When used on top of an ORM, LINQ is used as the ORM's query language, not a replacement for SQL. It's meant to load graphs of *objects*. The ORM converts the LINQ query to SQL. You *can't* use functions that don't map directly to SQL in a LINQ-to-Entities query. EF wouldn't know how to convert them

Comment: Besides, even if you can write a complex LINQ query that doesn't throw doesn't mean you *should*.  `someField LIKE '%banana%'` would force a full table scan because it can't take advantage of any indexes over `someField`

Comment: What are you trying to do? You can't use client functions in LINQ-to-Entities. What are the actual *entities* and their relations? `Table1` and `Table2` aren't entities. The typical name for a key is `ID`, not `Identifier`. `t2.Header == Decoder.Identifier` is used *twice* in the same condition. Shouldn't you use `(t1.Table2.Any(t2 => t2.Header == Decoder.Identifier) && DbFunctions.Like(t2.Content, pattern)) || (!t1.Table2.Any(t2 => t2.Header == Decoder.Identifier) && DbFunctions.Like(t1.Text, pattern))` instead?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The query by itself does exactly what it's supposed to do in the output SQL. I just try to find a way to make it more readable in code so when I look at it in 6 months I still can understand what the idea behind the filter condition is.

Comment: There's no SQL query here. That LINQ contains duplicate conditions. You can't use client functions. To make this more readable and *faster* you need to explain what the actual problem is, use your ORM as an ORM instead of embedded SQL. `when I look at it in 6 months` don't write such queries then. You missed the duplicate already. I repeat, EF is an ORM, LINQ isn't SQL. If you want to perform a full text search over multiple fields you need Full Text Search operators, which *are* available in DbFunctions and *can* work with multiple fields.

Comment: In any case, LINQ works with *expressions*, not functions. If you want to simplify this you need to create the necessary expressions instead of trying to call functions. For simple cases you can create an `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` and use it in LINQ-to-Entities. For more complex cases you need to use a library like [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) to create an expression that can be translated

Comment: The alternative to something like LINQKit that is easiest (the difficult way is to write your own version) would be to replace at the `Where` level - e.g. you could easily write an extension method `WhereAnyPattern<T>(IQueryable<T> q, string pattern) => q.Where(...)`

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [CompiledQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.compiledquery?view=netframework-4.8) (Or the EF core equivalent: [EF.CompileQuery()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ef.compilequery?view=efcore-6.0))